# How to add dynamically validators and filters to elements in fieldsets in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I use fieldsets in ZF2 forms. I can add validators and filters to elements:

```
$form->getInputFilter()->add(array(
    'name' => 'element_name',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array(
        array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'),
    ),            
));
```

But how can I do this if element is in fieldset?
I tried to do so:

```
$form->getInputFilter()->add(array(
    'fieldset_name' => array(
        'name' => 'element_name',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'),
        ),   
    ),                
));
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method of @Fouad Fodail should be preferred. The `InputSpecification` should be declared at the `FieldsetClass` itself. However if you need to do this like you asked it's just as simple:

```
$form->getInputFilter()
     ->get('fieldset_name')
     ->get('element_name')
     ->add($additionalFilter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement getInputFilterSpecification() method in your Fieldset Class and make the
required configurations there. This is necessary because the fleldset’s form receives all of its “InputFilter” specifications from the getInputFilterSpecification() methods of the referenced fleldsets.

```
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class MyFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       //...
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
         return array(
             'element_name' => array(
                 'filters' => array(),
                 'validators' => array(),
                 'properties' => array(),
                 'required' => true
             )
         );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the validators directly in the fieldsets, not in the form.

Comment: There is no method getInputFilter() in Zend\Form\Fieldset